# How to store HTML-Markup in the ID-Attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, store

I need to show for every link, dynamically some text with Java-Script (jQuery). The problem is that the text is also formatted as HTML, so this causes some problems in the later view. 
Now I am storing it in the ID-attribute, this works, but only without embedded HTML in it.

```
<?php
...
$desc = '<p style="color: red">some <span>data</span></p>';
echo '<a href="#" id="' . $desc . '">' . $key . '</a>';
?>
```

Ajax-requests are not allowed. Is there a simple way to reach this goal?

Comment: The answer is simple: Don't do it. HTML markup contains tons of stuff that is not allowed in an ID.

Comment: This is serious abuse of the `id` attribute

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `id` attribute is one of the least appropriate places for this (must be unique, cannot contain all characters). Use a `data-` attribute (introduced in HTML5 but also works in old browsers and without using a HTML5 doctype) instead:

```html
<a href="#" data-desc="....">
```

If you are using jQuery you can access it via `.data('desc')`, in plain JavaScript the most portable way is using `.getAttribute('data-desc')`. If you do not need to support older browsers, you can access the value via the `.dataset.desc` property.

In any case, you need to ensure that nothing breaks when inserting dynamic data in the attribute. Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) for this purpose:

```php
$desc = '<p style="color: red">some <span>data</span></p>';
echo '<a href="#" data-desc="' . htmlspecialchars($desc) . '">' . $key . '</a>';
```

Comment: +1. What about `<body onload="...">` I think it's even worse... `:)`

Comment: The only minor issue might be if he needs to validate below HTML5

Comment: That's an artificial issue though. For example, adding Facebook OpenGraph tags also cause your HTML to become invalid.

Comment: Okay, with htmlspecialchars() I will break the HTML down. But how to convert it back with Java-Script?

Comment: No need to do this. The function escapes the characters so when retrieving the attribute you get the proper data like they were *before* escaping.

Answer (score 1):

The other comments are absolutely right.  Don't do this.  It isn't appropriate to put anything but an identifier of some kind in the `id` attribute.

That being said, I figured I would let you know why your code is failing.  You need to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on your data before you try to use it as you intend.  That way, HTML won't be interpreted as HTML... all of the HTML entities will get converted for, so your attribute value is interpreted as text.  `<` becomes `&lt;`, `>` becomes `&gt;` and so on.  If you later pull the value out (with jQuery or whatever), you will get the text as intended.